# Initialize Ribbon base on version of Outlook (2007/2010) in Visual Studio 2010/VSTO 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm creating an Outlook add-in for 2007/2010 using Visual Studio 2010, VSTO 4.0

I have 3 Projects:

- 2010Ribbon (Ribbon1.cs, Ribbon2.cs)
- 2007Ribbon (Ribbon1-2007.cs, Ribbon2-2007.cs)
- shared code (class library)

I'm just trying to load the correct version of the ribbon (DESIGNER) based on the version

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        majorVersion = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version.Split(new char[] { '.' })[0];
        if (majorVersion == 12) //Outlook 2007
        {
            Initialize2007UI();  
        }
        else if (majorVersion >= 14) //Outlook 2010
        {
            Initialize2010UI();   
        }
    }
```

How do I implement Initialize2007UI() and Initialize2010UI(); to load their respective Ribbon1.cs in the Explorer window and Ribbon2.cs in the Inspector window?

thanks!!!!

Hope I'm clear on what i"M asking :)

Comment: did you ever figure this out . . i have a similar issue / requirement lisetd here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127476/for-outlook-vsto-how-can-you-generate-ribbon-tab-for-2010-users-and-regular-too

Answer (score 1):

probably this is what you are looking out for

```
protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    majorVersion = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version.Split(new char[] { '.' })[0];
        if (majorVersion == 12) //Outlook 2007
        {
             return new Ribbon2007();
        }
        else if (majorVersion >= 14) //Outlook 2010
        {
            return new Ribbon2010();
        }


}


[ComVisible(true)]
public class Ribbon2007: Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
                    var ribbonXml = GetResourceText("Ribbon2007.xml");                 
                    XNamespace nameSpace = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui";                  
                    return ribbonXml;
    }
}


[ComVisible(true)]
public class Ribbon2007: Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            var ribbonXml = GetResourceText("Ribbon2010.xml");                 
                    XNamespace nameSpace = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui";                  
                    return ribbonXml;
    }
}
```